# XCode 4.2 warns "Failed to save <projname>.xcodeproj", while opening project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos

This is not the same as the more common "Project file is write-protected, unlock?" dialog, often seen if your project is under source control.

Reloading my entire project from source control did not help, setting file/folder permissions from the command line did not help, and re-installing XCode did not help.

Comment: Yes, I'd done a chmod -R on the whole project folder.

Comment: This turns out to be caused by a near-full disk condition. My project is in a .sparsebundle with a max size of one GB, usually more than large enough. 
But I'd recently tried a lot of build variations, going from gcc to llvm, debug, release, sim, target, etc, and my DerivedData folder was full. Tossing it and emptying the trash cleared the warning.

Comment: I was just (un?)lucky that the prior build had barely squeezed onto the disk without error, but then a few revisions did me in.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer and then mark it as correct. Otherwise, it looks like this question is unresolved.

Comment: SO says I'm not worthy enough, and must wait awhile before posting an answer to my own question.

Comment: Used Xcode prefs to set a deriveddata folder on a big fast drive, that made everything work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Failed to Save" error from XCode4 seems to be caused by any generic file I/O error, in this case caused by a near-full .sparsebundle disk image. Making room by cleaning up the DerivedData folder solved the problem.

See my comments above for excuses as to why I didn't realize this to be the problem immediately.